# Imitation of select

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to imitate a  tag with a span. Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="field select-field">
    <select class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select Type of paper</option>
        <option value="1">Essay (any type)</option>
    </select>
    <span class="select" id="select-1">Select Type of paper</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.select-field {
        position: relative;
    }

    select::-ms-expand {
        display: none;
    }

    .select-field select {
        cursor: pointer;
        overflow: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    span.select {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        float: left;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        line-height: 38px;
        text-indent: 10px;
        cursor: default;
        z-index: 1;
        font-size: 14px;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: #b1a9bb;
        background: url(images/arrow.png) no-repeat right #e6e7e9;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
```

Select tag is invisible now and I need to get it active (you can get dropdown by clicking , span's content will be changed by JS).

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: it doesn't work.. I thought, z-index will solve the problem, but no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change position of class **select** to relative,
2. **Select** tag also must have relative postion.
3. Set height of a **select** tag for example to 38px.
4. Add minus top position of **select** class, -38px.

Should work.